# How to pipe different output when using "Restart-Computer" powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file

```
SERVERS|SEQUENCE|INDEX
ServerA|  1     | 1.1
ServerB|  1     | 2.1
ServerC|  2     | 3.1
```

And here is my Code

```
#importing csv into ps$
$csv = Import-Csv "sequencing.csv"

#Grouping & Sort data from csv
$objdata = $csv | Select SERVERS,SEQUENCE | Group SEQUENCE | Select @{n="SEQUENCE";e={$_.Name}},@{n="SERVERS";e={$_.Group | ForEach{$_.SERVERS}}} | Sort SEQUENCE
foreach ($d in $objdata)
    {
        $order = $d.SEQUENCE
        $cNames = $d.SERVERS

        if (Restart-Computer -ComputerName $cNames -Force -Wait -For Wmi -Delay 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            {
                 write-host "$cNames is rebooting" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        else
            {
            Write-Host "Unable to reboot $cNames remotely, Please do it manually" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
    }
```

I am trying to reboot multiple servers in sequence and piping the output through 2 different results.
From my code, all the servers will reboot but will output through the **else** statement.
Can anyone point me to the right direction?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: from the docs on that cmdlet ... `Outputs : None : Restart-Computer doesn't generate any output.` that means your `if` will always evaluate as `$False` ... and always run the `else` section. [*grin*] try using the `try/catch` structure instead.

Comment: Hey! thanks for answering! I'll give that a shot

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped little ... [*grin*]

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey I've tried using `try/catch`, due to the grouping of "SERVERS" the variable `$cNames` will always be pipe with all the server names of the same sequence.

Is there any way to only pipe servers with error?

Comment: you would have to re-write the `$objdata = ` line with a `foreach` loop to easily use `try/catch`. however, i was referring to the ` if (Restart-Computer` section. use `try/catch` instead of `if/else` for that section. the Answer by `Theo` shows the idea. [*grin*]

Comment: Hey @Lee_Dailey, thanks! I'll give that a try!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

As [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) already pointed out, the `Restart-Computer` does not return anything. That means you will have to use a `try/catch` block.

To make sure that in the event of an error you actually enter the catch block, you need to set the `ErrorAction` parameter to `Stop`.

In your code, you show a csv to import that has the piping symbol `|` as delimiter, so you need to specify that on the `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

From your latest comment, I gather that you want to loop one computer at a time, instead of restarting multiple computers at once, so you will know which computer errors out.

Try:

```
# importing csv into ps$
$csv = Import-Csv "D:\sequencing.csv" -Delimiter '|'

# Grouping & Sort data from csv
$objdata = $csv | Select-Object SERVERS,SEQUENCE | 
                  Group-Object SEQUENCE | 
                  Select-Object @{Name = "SEQUENCE"; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                                @{Name = "SERVERS"; Expression = {$_.Group.SERVERS}} | 
                  Sort-Object SEQUENCE

$objdata | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($server in $_.SERVERS) {
        try {
            Restart-Computer -ComputerName $server -Force -Wait -For Wmi -Delay 1 -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "Server $server is rebooting" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Unable to reboot $server remotely, Please do it manually" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
```

---

Seeing your latest comment, I understand that you only want to reboot servers where the SEQUENCE value in the CSV is set to '1'. Correct?

Also, you want to restart the servers at the same time, but also want to be able to see what server did not restart. Maybe you can do that with running `Restart-Computer -AsJob`, but I believe that only works in PowerShell 5.1

Below code filters out all servers with SEQUENCE set to `1` and restarts them one at a time (as requested in your original question "*I am trying to reboot multiple servers in sequence*"):

```
# import csv data
$csv = Import-Csv "D:\sequencing.csv" -Delimiter '|'  # change this to the delimiter actually used in the CSV !

# get the list of servers where SEQUENCE is set to '1'
$servers = $csv | Select-Object SERVERS,SEQUENCE |
                  Where-Object { $_.SEQUENCE.Trim() -eq '1' } |
                  ForEach-Object { $_.SERVERS.Trim() }

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    try {
        Restart-Computer -ComputerName $server -Force -Wait -For Wmi -Delay 1 -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Server $server is rebooting" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Unable to reboot $server remotely, Please do it manually" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Theo, I've given your code a shot, changed the csv file location but in foreach loop, $server return with no value.  `try/catch` will always be catching the error.
This is what i get `Unable to reboot  remotely, Please do it manually`

Comment: @Newt-010 That means Import-Csv uses the wrong delimiter character. Please right-click your CSV file, select 'Open With...' and choose Notepad. Then have a close look what character is used to separate the values. Change the `|` to that character in `-Delimiter '|'`

Comment: Thanks, i managed to find out my delimiter! Not very good with scripting.
Anyways, i realised that i missed out something. I do not want to loop one server at a time. Rather i'd want all `Sequence 1` to reboot at the same time. 

With the `try/catch` loop as suggested to catch any of the servers throwing out errors. Hope that clarifies!

Comment: @Newt-010 I have added new code. What you now want (reboot servers at the same time while still being able to get error messages from each server separate) _may_ be possible, but since your the question states _in sequence_, I'll not go that path.

Comment: Hey @theo, it seems i might have phrase wrongly, but really appreciate your help! I've learnt quite abit from you, thanks! I'll try out your new code.
If all else fails, i'll just go ahead and post a fresh post.
Thanks!